# What does sfdisk do, and how does it compare to fdisk or parted?

Tags: linux, partitioning, format, fdisk

I was looking over documentation for ZFS for Linux and I came accross a command that the instructions tell me to run to prepare a disk for use.

The command was;

```
sfdisk -q /dev/zvol/tank/fish << EOF
0,
EOF
```

*The line breaks are included the command took up 3 lines*

What does sfdisk do? Is it the same and creating a new partition table or is it something different?

Here is the documentation I was looking at, [Link](http://zfsonlinux.org/example-zvol.html)

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk here's the man page, although I don't know how helpful it'll be, it's a start.

Comment: I actually have that exact manpage open. I understand what `sfdisk -q` does, what I don't understand is the `<< EOF 0, EOF` part.

Answer (score 16):

sfdisk reads and writes partition tables, but is not interactive like fdisk or cfdisk (it reads input from a file or stdin).  It's generally used for partitioning drives from scripts or for partition table backup and recovery.  Since it's command driven instead of menu driven, I can see the attraction for using it in documentation like this, since you can easily document the input.

Answer (score 7):

sfdisk is nice for software raid. When replacing a disk, simply:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

and you've cloned the partition table from sda to sdb.

now just add back to mdadm and good to go.

Answer (score 4):

> sfdisk reads lines of the form
>
> `<start> <size> <id> <bootable> <c,h,s> <c,h,s>`
>
> where each line fills one partition descriptor.
>
> ... When a field is absent or empty, a default value is used.

So this sets up a new partition, starting at 0 and ending at the default of size.

> The default value of size is as much as possible (until next partition or end-of-disk).

Comment: So its just a quick way to partition the drive.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it seems like. I'd use something I was more comfortable with if it was available.

Comment: Yeah I agree, so according to what I listed that would create 1 partition that is the full size of the disk right? Because it shows me 4 partitions but only 1 was Linux and 3 were Empty.

Comment: It will create one partition, starting at the beginning of the disk, and ending the start of the next partition.